# Manual Update password Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an API based Rails app and I need to add a changing password section for clients after login. this is y codes so far:

```
# routes.rb
resources :passwords, only: %i[index]
      post '/passwords/update_password', to: 'passwords#update_password'
```

passwords_controller.rb

```
 class Api::PasswordsController < ApplicationController
        respond_to :json

        before_action :auth_check
        def auth_check
             if !user_signed_in? 
                render json: {:status => false, :msg => 'Access denied!'}
             end
        end

        def update_password
          user = User.find(current_user['_id'])
          password = params["password"]
          if password && !password.blank?
              user.password = user.password_confirmation = password
          end

          if user.save
            render json: {company: user}, status: 200
          else
            render json: {message: "Problem updating company"}, status: 500
          end
        end
    end
```

And this is XHR request from client-side

```
axios({
              url: '/api/passwords/update_password',
              method: 'POST',
              body: {
                password: password,
                password_confirmation: password_confirmation
              }
          })
          .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
          });
```

Its not working!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use current_user. I edited the code. If it doesn't work, can you write the error here? Make sure the post request goes to update_password action.

```
class Api::PasswordsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  before_action :auth_check

  def update_password
    password = params.dig(:password)
    password_confirmation = params.dig(:password_confirmation)
    if password.present? && password == password_confirmation
      if current_user.update(password: password, pasword_confirmation: password_confirmation)
        render json: { company: user }, status: 200
      else
        render json: { message: 'Problem updating company' }, status: 500
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def auth_check
    render json: { status: false, msg: 'Access denied!' } unless user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

Comment: ``Mongoid::Errors::UnknownAttribute (
 message:
   Attempted to set a value for 'pasword_confirmation' which is not allowed on the model User.
 summary:
   Without including Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic in your model and the attribute does not already exist in the attributes hash, attempting to call User#pasword_confirmation= for it is not allowed. This is also triggered by passing the attribute to any method that accepts an attributes hash, and is raised instead of getting a NoMethodError.
 resolution:
   You can include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic if you expect to be writing va...``

Comment: User model seems to have a problem. Did you include `Mongoid :: Attributes :: Dynamic` in the User model?

Comment: this is how my model starts: ``class User
  include Mongoid::Document``